# jQuery scripts not loading on Angular v4

Tags: jquery, angular

I have a template that have a 2 thousand lines JQuery script. Originally I got it with angular version 1 and it works perfectly there, but when importing it on Angular 4 seems that the JQuery is not loaded when doc is ready.

In the end of the file, I have:

```
(function($) {
  'use strict';
  // Initialize layouts and plugins
  (typeof angular === 'undefined') && $.Pages.init();
})(window.jQuery);
```

Maybe something related to Angular version or something like that. Can't figure it out yet.

Comment: Not 100% sure but I think only Angular 1 was using jQuery under the bonnet when the new versions don't so it's possible that jQuery is no longer available and that you have to provide it yourself.

Comment: I can use JQuery on Angular 2 directives easily. I think there are some way to call the init method that matches with the requirements of the new version.

Answer (score 0):

Solved my problem after looking into Angular docs about `ngAfterViewInit`

```
import { Component, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app works!';

  constructor(private _elementRef:ElementRef) {};

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    var s = document.createElement("script");
    s.type = "text/javascript";
    s.src = "../assets/js/pages.js";
    this._elementRef.nativeElement.appendChild(s);
  }
}
```

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/AfterViewInit-class.html